# How to remove Program Events from the Sound control panel?

Tags: windows, windows-8, tortoise-svn, system-sounds

I have Program Events in the Sound control panel (mmsys.cpl) for TortoiseSVN, which is no longer installed on my computer.

How can I remove them?

I have tried reinstalling and unintallting the program, but that didn't help.

[image: Missing program in Sound]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would start by deleting *all* registry keys containing the string "TortoiseSVN".

If you just want to remove the offending key, "EventLabels" looks promising:

> -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>
> ---> AppEvents
>
> ------>EventLabels:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was close enough. They were in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\TortoiseProc`